# Вопрос по Python и threading

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, beautiful-soup, pthread

Код, скрипт парсера, парсит оочень большое колличество ссылок, и выполняется оочень долго, минут 40. Я решил залезть в многопоточность, чтоб все это  работало побыстрее,но так я ничего и не понял. Помогите, как ускорить данный код с помощью библиотеки threading. Может нужно первую функцию запускать, и что бы вторая функция не ждала полного завершения работы первой. Ну или как, объясните пожалуйста. Ниже код, но он выдает ошибку (

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import csv
import threading

urls_list = []

def pars_url(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    urls = soup.select('loc')
    for url in urls:
        url_list = url.text.split('/')
        if len(url_list) > 5:
            urls_list.append(url.text)      
        else:
            pass

t = threading.Thread(target=pars_url, name='Thread1', args=('https://xn----8sbatmpykxep.xn--p1ai/sitemap.xml'))


def all_pars(list):
    for url in list:
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
        artikul = soup.select('#product_model')
        application = soup.select('#tab-methoduse > p')
        contraindications = soup.select('#tab-contraindications > p')
        
t.start()
all_pars(urls_list)
```

Скинте ссылку на обучение или разъяснение для чайников по threading

Comment: Вот тут довольно понятно написано: https://python-scripts.com/threading Создайте 2 потока для двух долгих функций (или, если их больше можно 3-4 потока, **но главное НЕ слишком много**). Если всё же функций больше чем кол-во ядер процессора, то исследуйте очередь

Comment: @Стас т.е. мне нужно создать 1 поток на одну функцию, другой на другую?

Comment: Только потоки вряд ли дадут Вам прирост производительности. См. [GIL](https://habr.com/ru/post/84629/).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов но что мне тогда делать, как ускорить? При последовательном запуске функций, сначала первая которая парсит один сайт и оттуда забирает огромное количество ссылок (где то +-2ка), затем вторая, парсит каждую ссылку. Выполняется где то за 40 мин. Думал многопоток...

Comment: сколько времени выполняется первая функция и сколько вторая ?

Comment: @PustovoyAndrei Использовать `multiprocessing`, а не `threading`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов хорошо посмотрю,спасибо